# What happens when the cpu loads a value that is stored in the L2 cache. Does it put it in the L1 cache?

Tags: c++, caching, cpu, cpu-cache

Lets say i have a basic matrix multiplication and the code needs some values, that are already in the L2 cache from previous calculations. Will it put these values in the L1 cache or just leave it in the L2 cache?

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on the cpu. Though in most cases i'd expect anything that ends up in a cacheline to ultimately wind up in the L1 cache.

Comment: When you read some data, it usually ends up in the L1 cache. What could differ is what happens to the L2 cache: L2 will have the data as well (inclusive policy) or L2 won't have the data (exclusive policy). This policy depends on the CPU.